# How to install PostgreSQL-contrib-9.3 on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm trying to get PostgreSQL up and running on my MacOSX 10.9.4.

I successfully installed PostgreSQL itself using Homebrew by following the instructions listed here: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-install-postgresql. It's up and I can connect to it using the `psql` command.

However, when I try to create the postgis extension, it fails (see below). I understand I need to install `postgresql-contrib-9.3`.

```
$ psql -d mydb
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

How can I install this `postgresql-contrib-9.3` on Mac OSX? I don't have `apt-get`. The instructions I have seen are not at all clear how to install it. Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://postgis.net/install:

```
$ brew install postgis
<SNIP SNIP>

$ psql -d mydb
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help.

dbname=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Answer (score 2):

On postgresql 9.4 contrib seems to be a part of the default installation. I was able to install cube and earthdistance like

```
PGUSER=postgres psql my-db
create extension cube;
create extension earthdistance;
```

from a default macports postgresql94-server installation.